# How to implement a chat list view with heterogenous row types (image video and text) using listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, chat, android-recyclerview

I'm building a normal chat application. Image,text and videos can be sent hence I need multiple row styles in my list. I used listview. But Listview returned (after recycling rows) wrong rows many times and my attempt failed. Any Idea how to do this? Can this be done using RecyclerView?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with recyclerview. Here is what I did for displaying multiple types of rows in a single recyclerview

```
// Different types of rows
private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Viewholder for row type 0
}

class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Viewholder for row type 1
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Here you have to write logic for which position have which type of row and return the same
    if (position == 0) {
        return TYPE_ITEM0;
    } else {
        return TYPE_ITEM1;
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolder0(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.itme0, viewGroup, false););
         case 1: return new ViewHolder1(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item1, viewGroup, false););
         ...
     }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
     if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == TYPE_ITEM0) {
         // Code to populate type 0 view here
     } else if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == TYPE_ITEM1) {
         // code to populate type 1 view here
     }
}
```